# "When is the next release of inflationary tokens?"

Tags: inflation

"When is the next release of inflationary tokens?"   The inflation rate is 4.73%, when do those tokens (the 4.73%) get distributed?  When is the next distribution, date and time?

Answer (score 0):

Before being distributed to the bakers, rewards are frozen during 5 cycles (approximately two weeks). These distributions happen once per cycle (so approximately every 2.8 days).